# Can I make a reference to a field class dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, reference, field

I have a class called `Bird` that is composed of 3 string fields, each of which is the name in a different language, say `Bird.lang1`, `Bird.lang2`, `Bird.lang3`. And I have an instance of Bird called `allbirds`.

Now I want to make a list of strings `ListOfAllBirds` with the names of all birds, in the language the user choices, that is stored in the `lang` variable, whose value is one of `lang1`, `lang2`, `lang3`. And I need to do this hundreds of times (call this number of times `N`).

Of course, I can do an iterator over all Bird elements, and add the corresponding field to that of `lang`. But this implies in `3 x N x Bird.size()` (that is, hundreds of thousands!!) conditional queries to test the language the user choose.

Can I do something like

```
varfield = lang.toField();
for (Bird birdy : allbirds)
    ListOfAllBirds.add(birdy.varfield);
```

That is, can I make a reference to a field with a variable?? This would save me tons of conditional queries!

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you store the strings in a string array and access them by index?

Comment: @MAV: sure. But how would this save me resources? Wouldn't this imply in many opperations in any case?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit If your language setting is an int corresponding to the correct index, it will work great.

Comment: @Vulcan: no, `lang` is a String.

Comment: Then make change it to an `int` corresponding to each language, and take that approach.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: Of course I can make one loop for each language, but I want to prevent this.

Comment: Eh?  The suggestion is to replace your three fields `lang1`, `lang2`, and `lang3` with a `String[3]`, which would make it much easier to operate over them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the difference. If you prefer, call them `lang[1]`, `lang[2]`, `lang[3]`. Same problem applies: how to convert a `String` into a `ClassField`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, sorry, my question was stupid... :o(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant with using a String array was something like this (if you do not want to change your language setting to an int as Vulcan suggested).

```
String chosenLanguage = "Language 2";
int languageIndex = -1;
switch(chosenLanguage)
{
    case "Language 1": 
        languageIndex = 0;
        break;
    case "Language 2":
        languageIndex = 1;
        break;
    case "Language 3":
        languageIndex = 2;
        break;
    default:
        languageIndex = 0;
        break;
}

for (Bird birdy : allbirds)
       ListOfAllBirds.add(birdy.names[languageIndex]);
```

Your class would then look like this:

```
class Bird
{
    public String[] names = {"name1", "name2", "name3"};
}
```

instead of

```
class Bird
{
    public String lang1 = "name1";
    public String lang2 = "name2";
    public String lang3 = "name3";
}
```

This way you only have to check for the language chosen by the user once (to find the index) and you can then iterate through all birds and get the correct name based on the index.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. What kind of object `names` is in your code? Even if `names` is an `int[]` I don't see how this can work... Your `names` should be something like `ClassField[]`, that does not exist.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Updated my answer. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Mmm... I see what you mean. Will try to implement it, and inform back. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Actually, instead of a `String[3]` `names` could be a `Map`?

Comment: Yes.... now I understood what you meant. And I also understood how STUPID my question was! And your solution is nice. Thanks a lot for your patience with this newbie!